# I want to add the userid I have obtained from the user. But I don't know how to add multipartformdatacontent () with request.UserID field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to add the userid I have obtained from the user. But I don't know how to add multipartformdatacontent () with request.UserID field

```cs
public async Task<bool> CreateDocument(DocumentsCreateRequest request)
{
    var sessions = _httpContextAccessor
        .HttpContext
        .Session
        .GetString(SystemConstants.AppSettings.Token);

    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("BackendApi");
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration[SystemConstants.AppSettings.BaseAddress]);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", sessions);
    var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var claimsIdentity = this._httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (request.DocumentFile != null)
    {
        byte[] data;
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(request.DocumentFile.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            data = br.ReadBytes((int)request.DocumentFile.OpenReadStream().Length);
        }
        ByteArrayContent bytes = new ByteArrayContent(data);
        requestContent.Add(bytes, "documentFile", request.DocumentFile.FileName);
    }
    var userId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value.ToString();
    requestContent.Add(new StringContent(userId), "userId", request.UserID.ToString()); 
    var response = await client.PostAsync($"/api/documents/", requestContent);
    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

Comment: the `MultipartFormDataContent.Add` method you use has the third parameter for a *filename*. Looks like you just need this `requestContent.Add(new StringContent(userId), "userId")`. However still not sure how exactly it's not working on your side. Can you debug on the endpoint `/api/documents/` to see what's received?

Comment: Thank you about that, this is already works for me

Answer (score 0):

replace this code `var userId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value.ToString();`  with `var userid =claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);` or `var loggedInUserId = claimsIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`